# Font value of a?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm going over the Shay Howe HTML/CSS tutorial and it includes the following example in codepen. http://codepen.io/shayhowe/pen/gblxy

I have no clue what the letter a means in the value for the font property. I would really appreciate it if someone can explain it to me.

HTML

- Bold Text
- Italicize Text
- Underline Text
- Size Text
- Bullet Text
- Number Text
- Quote Text
- Left Align Text
- Center Align Text
- Right Align Text

CSS

```
li span {
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/sprite.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
  display: block;
  font: 0/0 a; */the a right here */
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}
```

Comment: 0/0 = fontsize/rowsize. 'a' is some font named "a", which could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`font: 0/0 a;`](http://nicolasgallagher.com/another-css-image-replacement-technique/) - Is a shorthand property that zeros out the font size and line-height. The **a** value acts as a very short font-family (an idea taken from the BEM implementation of this method). The CSS validator complains that using **0/0** in the shorthand font property is not valid, but every browser accepts it and this appears to be an error in the validator. Using **font:0px/0 a** passes validation but it displayed as **font:0/0 a** in the code that the validator flags as valid.